# I have not call xml file in java.class but activity is still coming?

Tags: android

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
}
```

As i have not called activity_main still an activity is coming in output.How to hide that activity?

Answer (score 2):

Removing the layout is not a solution.

As you are only removing the layout defined by you. One of the indirect Superclass of MainActivity defines a default layout that get inflated when you call `super.onCreate(...)`. Basically it remove child views defined by you in layout.

To avoid the activity from loading you need to remove its declaration the `AndroidManifest.xml`. The activity will not loaded than.

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

But to successfully run the app there should be at least one main activity with the `intent-filter` defined by above code otherwise Andorid system can not start your application.

or

You can create another activity in your application and change the name of `MainActivity` in `AndroidManifest.xml`

Hope it helps.

Comment: should I have to remove MainActivity declaration from manifest?